# Set Width of a div with respect to that of another div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs aligned as grid like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="col-1-10 a">...</div>
    <div class="col-9-10 b">...</div>
</div>
```

I need to ensure that the `div` with class `col-1-10` has a minimum width of `85 px` to accommodate some things as per requirements. The `div` with class `col-9-10` should take up the remaining width.

Currently I am doing this:

```
.a{
    @media (max-width: 850px){
        width:85px;
    }
}

.b{
    @media (max-width: 850px){
        max-width:765px;
    }
}
```

This works fine with the first `div`, However, the second `div` gets pushed below instead of getting displayed inline. I basically want the width of the second `div` to be the width of the parent `div` - 85 and that too with **CSS only**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also post code for your `.col-1-10` and `col-9-10` as there may be some borders or padding there to.

Comment: Use Flexbox. .container {
    display: flex;
}

.left {
    width: 180px;
}

.r {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

Comment: @OkeTega I can't add the code for that here because its too complex.
Its got a margin of 8 px to both left and right

Comment: Just put the margins into consideration when calculating your measurements

Comment: unless you use the table display (where you need to use border-spacing) , margin remains margin and with a good choice of technic to use, there is no need to mind about more than setting margins value.

Answer (score 2):

There is a few options from `float` (content standing side by side)  to display via `table`/`flex`/`grid` (content standing in columns) :
These 4 'easy' ways

- `float` understood by every browsers
- `table`/`table-cell` in CSS spec since 1998 (usable from IE 8 ...)
- `Flex` usable nowdays with nowdays browsers
- `grid` usable in Chrome and Firefox if experimental CSS is flagged on.

Snippet below to test behavior in your browser:

```css
div {
  border: solid;
  padding:8px;
}

.a {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.a {
  background: tomato;
}

.b {
  background: orange
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex .a {
  min-width: 85px;
}

.flex .b {
  flex: 1;
}

.small {
  width: 200px;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 8px;
  padding:0;
}

.table.small {
  width: 200px;
}

.table .a {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 85px;
}

.table .b {
  display: table-cell;
}

.float .a {
  float: left;
  min-width: 85px;
}

.float .b {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex,
.table,
.float,
.grid {
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(85px, 120px) 1fr;
}

.grid.bis {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(85px, 1fr) 1fr;
}
```

```html
<h1>float layout</h1>
<div class="float">
  <div class="col-1-10 a">float float float float float float , I can grow </div>
  <div class="col-9-10 b">...</div>
</div>
<div class="float small">
  <div class="col-1-10 a">...</div>
  <div class="col-9-10 b">block block block block block block, I can shrink</div>
</div>

<h1>table layout</h1>
<div class="table">
  <div class="col-1-10 a">table-cell, I cannot grow unless content pieces are wider than the initial 85px (img, long word, .. ) </div>
  <div class="col-9-10 b">...</div>
</div>
<div class="table small">
  <div class="col-1-10 a"></div>
  <div class="col-9-10 b">table-cell table-cell table-cell, table-cell , I can shrink</div>
</div>

<hr/>
<hr/>
<h1>Flex layout</h1>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="col-1-10 a">flex flex flex flex flex , I can grow </div>
  <div class="col-9-10 b">...</div>
</div>
<div class="flex small">
  <div class="col-1-10 a"></div>
  <div class="col-9-10 b">flex flex flex flex flex , I can shrink</div>
</div>
<hr/>

<h1>grid layout</h1>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-1-10 a">grid cell , i can have a min and width or I can grow </div>
  <div class="col-9-10 b">...</div>
</div>
<div class="grid bis">
  <div class="col-1-10 a">grid cell , i can have a min and or share the pace with others </div>
  <div class="col-9-10 b">...</div>
</div>
<div class="grid small">
  <div class="col-1-10 a">...</div>
  <div class="col-9-10 b">grid cell , I can shrink</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could post just one way so the rest of us get a chance too .... :) .. upvoted

Comment: @VarunSharma just saw your comment, so I added theses margins in the snippet answer to show that it is also not that complex ;)